# How and where are the Python keywords assigned a syntax highlighting type in blender?

Tags: python, text-editor

Blender has a colour assigned for Builtins, Symbol, Special, Preprocessor, Reserved, Comment, String and Numbers.

[image]
*The text editor theme for syntax highlighting*

While testing importing [Vim](https://vim.org) colorschemes to blender I noticed there is quite some variance in keyword assignment.

[Vim](https://vim.org) uses a syntax file to highlight colors from the colorscheme

Snip from vim syntax file for python `python.vim`

```
"
" Keywords
"

syn keyword pythonStatement     break continue del
syn keyword pythonStatement     exec return
syn keyword pythonStatement     pass raise
syn keyword pythonStatement     global assert
syn keyword pythonStatement     lambda
syn keyword pythonStatement     with
syn keyword pythonStatement     def class nextgroup=pythonFunction skipwhite
syn keyword pythonRepeat        for while
syn keyword pythonConditional   if elif else
syn keyword pythonImport        import
syn keyword pythonException     try except finally
syn keyword pythonOperator      and in is not or
```

[image]
*My current result for importing the github colorscheme*

How and where are the python keywords assigned to syntax type in blender.  Can they be modified using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing syntax highlighting in the editor requires parsers for the programming languages in order to identify keywords. These parsers can be found in `source/blender/editors/space_text`. Currently implement are `text_format_lua.c`, `text_format_osl.c`, `text_format_pov.c`, `text_format_pov_ini.c` and `text_format_py.c`. Each of these implementation provides a functions to map strings to internal identifier types which can later be used to give these a distinct color, e.g. in case of the Python:

```
static void txtfmt_py_format_line(SpaceText *st, TextLine *line, const bool do_next)
```

Every format implementation provide a function to register the parser as well as the formatter. They are called `ED_text_format_register_` followed by the language suffix. Ultimately they all call `ED_text_format_register` to register the callback functions. The registration using `ED_text_format_register_` functions is performed once in `source/blender/editors/space_text/space_text.c` by calling:

```
void ED_spacetype_text(void)
```

Once this is completed the text can be formatted and syntax highlighted by

```
void draw_text_main(SpaceText *st, ARegion *ar)
```

which can be found in `source/blender/editors/space_text/text_draw.c`. This function retrieves the pointers to formatting callbacks for a given text using `tft = ED_text_format_get(text);`. The return value can then be used to call the callback with `tft->format_line(st, tmp, false);`. In case the current language is Python that would result in a call to `txtfmt_py_format_line`. It stores identifiers / format character in `tmp` which can then be used to highlight keywords by one of the drawing functions `text_draw`, `text_draw_wrapped` and `draw_suggestion_list`. Each of them will call the function:

```
static void format_draw_color(const TextDrawContext *tdc, char formatchar)
```

This functions contains a switch statement that identifies which format character is given and applies the matching color from the theme. For example if the format character would be `FMT_TYPE_KEYWORD` it would set the color with `UI_FontThemeColor(tdc->font_id, TH_SYNTAX_B)`. The parameter `TH_SYNTAX_B` determines the color.

In `source/blender/editors/interface/resource.c` is the function that is parsing this color id `TH_SYNTAX_B` to retrieve the actual color.

```
const uchar *UI_ThemeGetColorPtr(bTheme *btheme, int spacetype, int colorid)
```

This function use `ts->syntaxb` when the color id is `TH_SYNTAX_B` where `ts` is a pointer to a `ThemeSpace`.

The place where `syntaxb` is assigned its value is in `release/datafiles/userdef/userdef_default_theme.c`. The value is given in `.space_text` as

```
.syntaxb = RGBA(0xff1961ff),
```

For this `syntaxb` we have a matching RNA property definition in `source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_userdef.c`

```
  prop = RNA_def_property(srna, "syntax_builtin", PROP_FLOAT, PROP_COLOR_GAMMA);
  RNA_def_property_float_sdna(prop, NULL, "syntaxb");
  RNA_def_property_array(prop, 3);
  RNA_def_property_ui_text(prop, "Syntax Built-in", "");
  RNA_def_property_update(prop, 0, "rna_userdef_theme_update");
```

The property `syntax_builtin` can be set in the Blender theme. For instance `release/scripts/presets/interface_theme/blender_light.xml` sets `syntax_builtin` to:

```
syntax_builtin="#ff1961"
```

Comment: It's not so much the color which I can get from the theme, rather the which keywords are assigned to which type.

Comment: @batFINGER Oh I see. Have to check. BTW `def`, `class` etc. aren't considered "keywords". They are affected by the Syntax Special setting.

Comment: @batFINGER  the formats and highlighting rules are defined in `source/blender/editors/space_text` with different files for the languages. `text_format_py.c`, `text_format_pov_ini.c`, `text_format_pov.c`, `text_format_osl.c`, `text_format_lua.c`. So you have to modify the source, nothing that can be done in python.

Comment: Cool, edit into answer and will accept. Not after modifying just after the set of keywords associated with type to compare with the vim set of same type as shown in question.  Thanks again. Oh and god knows which _python.vim_ that one is...  plucked it from a folder search for example paste. Thanks for heads up tho.

Comment: @batFINGER edited the answer. Let me know if there is something else you need.

Comment: @batFINGER updated the answer again for a more detailed explanation how the formatting works.